# RAID 0: how identical do the drives have to be?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-0

I have a spare 1Tb. Seagate Barracuda HD, and I was planning on buying another one and creating a RAID 0 array using my motherboard's SATA controller... but I have a doubt: how "identical" do the two drives have to be? I can buy another 1Tb. Seagate Barracuda with the same specs (speed, cache size...), but it will be difficult to get another one from the same batch or with the exact same model number. Will this cause me any trouble?

EDIT: forgot to mention: my motherboard is a Gigabyte P55-USB3, so I'm using the Intel SATA controller on it for the RAID.

Comment: The same model is identical enough. If the same model is not available an HDD of the same vendor and specifications will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entirely depends on your RAID controller, which you havent mentioned.  From my experience RAID controllers are very forgiving when it comes to non matching drives.  However, there are some that will complain, or wont even work drive if a drive is different enough.  Low end RAID controllers that are found on motherboards tend to be the former, so you should be OK.

Comment: My motherboard is a Gigabyte P55-USB3, so I'm using the Intel P55 SATA controller on it. Would that be okay?